# How do I create a Camera function in LibGdx?

Tags: java, libgdx

I'd like to take picture from the device's camera. How do I do that? I have no idea how to create a Camera Project in Libgdx.

Comment: What have you tried so far? A quick search would show you to the wiki with a tutorial...https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Integrating-libgdx-and-the-device-camera

Comment: What do they mean by Initialize your Application in the !MainActivity class in the Android project, but modify the AndroidApplicationConfiguration object? I don't know how to do it. @KleoG

Comment: Do you know Object Oriented programming? if not, check out some Java tutorials and get a hang of using objects and classes before attempting this. It would greatly help.

Comment: Do you have recommendations for tutorials? Or do you have an example on how to do it? @KleoG

Comment: There should be a vast amount of resources online for Java, https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/ is one and so is https://www.javatpoint.com/java-tutorial to get you started, you would also need to take a look at Android (which is https://developer.android.com/guide/index.html) but i recommend doing that after learning Java.